# How to handle ESLint error during type casting of document.getElementById() method in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

According to all of these pages:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491932/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65514898/470749
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

I expected this to work:

```
/**
 * Destroy current user session.
 */
function logOut() {
  const form = document.getElementById('logout-form') as HTMLFormElement;
  form.submit();
}
```

Instead, I see this ESLint error in VS Code:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

[image]

This approach threw errors, too: `const form = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('logout-form');`

I've tried this same function in both a .tsx file and a .ts file.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm using Prettier and ESLint and https://github.com/airbnb/javascript rules and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64166241/470749

Comment: You can see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669404/typescript-problems-with-type-system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/eslint-for-typescript/#Installation-and-setup was super helpful.

I think the main key was to change `parser` in my `.eslintrc.js` file to `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',`.

I also adjusted `plugins` and `extends` as instructed.

Then I added these lines to the `rules` object in my `.eslintrc.js` because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64024916/:

```
// We must disable the base rule (since it can report incorrect errors) and replace it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64024916/):
'no-use-before-define': 'off',
'@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ['error'],
```